# How to get text from Shared file on Google drive using applescript

Tags: text, applescript

I'm trying to read text from a shared file on Google drive using applescript, but I don't want to show any window on screen. If the file is on my drive folder, I can read text from my google drive folder, but the shared file is on Shared with me folder.
 I think there are 2 ways to do this.

1, Read text from the Shared with me file on web site.

2, Add shared file to my drive and read text from the file on file my drive folder

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you have the URL of the file and you can use `do shell script` to run `curl http://... -o localFile`

Comment: Thank you, but I can't really understand. Because I'm beginner. Could you give me a full script

Comment: Can you look at the file that is shared with you using your web-browser? If you can, copy the address at the top of your browser, something like `http://google.com/something`. Then start a Terminal on your Mac and run `curl THE_COPIED_ADDRESS -o $HOME/Desktop/file.txt` and see if the file arrives on your Desktop.

Comment: I did it and the file arrives but it said "Moved Temporarily
The document has moved here. "

Comment: Try adding `-L`, like this `curl -L http://.....`

Answer (score 0):

Can you look at the file that is shared with you using your web-browser? If you can, copy the address at the top of your browser, something like http://google.com/something. Then start a Terminal on your Mac and run curl -L THE_COPIED_ADDRESS -o $HOME/Desktop/file.txt and see if the file arrives on your Desktop.